# How to Parse XML Data

Tags: java, xml

I am having an XML,which is like

```
<polygon>
<coordinates>
<coordinate order="1" long="75.9375" lat="32.91648534731439"/>
<coordinate order="2" long="76.640625" lat="23.241346102386135"/>
<coordinate order="3" long="88.59375" lat="31.052933985705163"/>
</coordinates>
</polygon>
```

I want to get the long and lat values of every coordinates and assign to string.
I was trying like :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                    Document document = db.parse( new InputSource(new StringReader(s)));
                    System.out.println(document.getChildNodes());

                    NodeList nl = document.getElementsByTagName("coordinates");
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
                    {
                      System.out.println("name is : "+nl.item(i).getNodeName());
                      System.out.println("name is : "+nl.item(i).getNodeValue());


                    }
```

The String reader is the XML String I pass,but I am not able to get the data.

Comment: have you tried debugging your code ?

Comment: not particularly about this question but in general : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow?cb=1

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast each `Node` into an `Element`, and you need to make sure you're getting the right elements.

```
for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    Element e = (Element)nl.item(i);

    String lat = e.getAttribute("lat");

    String longStr = e.getAttribute("long");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create the NodeList based on your hierarchy** like below. Once you reach the childNode start iterating the nodelist casting with the  Element and try to fetch the attribute value using the **elementObject.getAttribute("tagname").**

XML Structure:

**polygon -> coordinates ->coordinate -> attributes - lat and long**

```
NodeList valueList = doc.getElementsByTagName("polygon");
for (int i = 0; i < valueList.getLength(); ++i)
{
    Element labTest = (Element) valueList .item(i);
    String labTestType = labTest.getAttribute("type");

    NodeList coordinates= labTest.getElementsByTagName("coordinates");
    for (int j = 0; j < coordinates.getLength(); ++j)
    {
        Element value = (Element) coordinates.item(j);
        String valueType = value.getAttribute("type");

        NodeList coordinate= value.getElementsByTagName("coordinate");
        for (int k = 0; k < coordinate.getLength(); ++k)
        {
            Element condition = (Element) coordinate.item(k);
            String lat = e.getAttribute("lat");

            String long = e.getAttribute("long");
        }
    }
}
```